# Let $T: \mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}^4$ be any linear transformation. Then how can I show that $T$ has a proper non zero invariant subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Let $T: \mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}^4$ be any linear transformation. Then how can I show that $T$ has a proper non zero invariant subspace.

If $T$ has an eigen value then it is clear but if not then I can't solve it. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: @RafayA. Then $\mathbb{R}^4$ is an invariant subspace, isn't it?

Comment: I deleted the original comment, but yeah, any subspace of $\mathbb R^4$ would be if $T$ were the zero map.

Comment: One approach would be to invoke a [real Jordan normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form#Real_matrices) of a matrix.  You've not given Readers much idea about what studies in linear algebra you've reached, though the reference to eigenvalues gives a little insight.

Comment: What if we are given $\mathbb{Q}^{4} $ instead of $\mathbb{R}^{4} $?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial has real coefficients. Therefore if all roots are non-real, they come in pairs that are conjugate of each other.

This means that the polynomial factors into two real polynomials of degree $2$.

You can reduce it to its [real Jordan form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form#Real_matrices) and that gives you a proper invariant subspace generated by the basis vectors corresponding to the columns of the first diagonal block.

Comment: What happens if the minimal and hence the characteristic polynomial is product of $2$ degree $2$ irreducibles ? how can you apply Jordan form ?

Comment: @user371231 Yes, it doesn't matter that the degree $2$ factors don't factor any further. In fact, we are assuming that they don't factor further over the reals. If they do factor over the reals you would just use the corresponding real eigenvalue. Be careful with your use of the word "irreducible" here irreducibility over $\mathbb{Q}$ is not relevant.

Comment: Suppose the Ch poly is $(x^2+1)(x^2+2).$ Then can you explain what happens ?

Comment: @user371231 Did you follow the link to the Wikipedia article?

Comment: No not really. May be that example clarify my doubts ! Jordan form will be complex matrix. How do I get real subspace ?

Comment: @user371231 They also merged this question with another that also has the explanation. In your example, although $\pm i$ and $\pm i\sqrt{2}$ are not real eigenvalues, if you take the subspace generated by the real an imaginary parts of a *complex* eigenvector for, say $i$, that will be an invariant subspace. It will be the same space as if you took the subspace generated by the real and imaginary parts of a complex eigenvector for $-i$.